# Failed to start GNOME DIsplay Manager

Tags: server, gnome, ssh, 22.04, xorg

I am trying to create a custom Ubuntu 22.04 bootable image. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 live server ISO and as per requirements I am installing few packages in the chroot environment. I am rebuilding the ISO file out of these installed custom packages.

Similarly I am trying to install "ubuntu-gnome-desktop" and it seems that it installs properly and I am successfully able to build the ISO file, however when I flash this ISO file on VM (VirtualBox) I get error messages saying `Failed to start GNOME Display Manager`. [Error While Flashing Image on VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fq5t.png). I can ssh and access, but the GUI doesn't start.

I found some logs using `systemctl` and `journalctl` as shown below.

[image: Systemctl error details]

[image: journalctl details]

The errors states that it can't find gdm user. I verified before squashing the filesystem  whether gdm user exists or not and it did, before flashing the custom image on VMm however after flashing the image when I ssh and verify it seems that while installing the system on VM it removes all the users created by ubuntu-gnome-desktop.

Users checked in the filesystem(in chroot) before squashing

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
_apt:x:100:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-network:x:101:102:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-resolve:x:102:103:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
messagebus:x:103:104::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-timesync:x:104:105:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/usr/sbin/nologin
pollinate:x:105:1::/var/cache/pollinate:/bin/false
sshd:x:106:65534::/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
colord:x:107:114:colord colour management daemon,,,:/var/lib/colord:/usr/sbin/nologin
geoclue:x:108:115::/var/lib/geoclue:/usr/sbin/nologin
pulse:x:109:116:PulseAudio daemon,,,:/run/pulse:/usr/sbin/nologin
gdm:x:110:118:Gnome Display Manager:/var/lib/gdm3:/bin/false
```

Users after flashing the image:

Output of `/etc/passwd` :

[image: output of /etc/passwd]

I've been stuck here for ages now. I can't figure out whats wrong.